# Refactoring several mongoose models to similar collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, node-modules

I have several collections that have the same documents type, except for the language.
Let's say imagesES, imagesEN, imagesFR, and so on....

I just thought about definig just one schema, but also one model that get the proper collection with a parameter:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var Schema = mongoose.Schema
let authorSchema = require('./Authors').authorSchema

const  imageSchema = new Schema({
  authors: [authorSchema],
  status: Number, // published (1), unpublished (0)
  created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  lastUpdated: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  license: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['Creative Commons BY-NC-SA'], //just one license right now
    default: 'Creative Commons BY-NC-SA'
  },
  downloads: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  },
  tags: [String]
})

module.exports = locale => {
  return mongoose.model('Image', imageSchema, `image${locale}`)
}
```

However in the controller I should require the model inside the controller (when I know the locale):

```
  getImageById: (req, res) => {
    const id = req.swagger.params.id.value
    const locale = req.swagger.params.locale.value
    const Images = require('../models/Images')(locale)
    Images.findOne({_id: id}).lean().exec( (err, image) => {
```

I'm not sure if this is the proper way as each request I get I have to require the model module (syncronously) or should I require all the different models previous to the use in the function.

```
const locales = ['es', 'en', 'fr']
const Images = []
locales.map(locale=>Images[locale] = require('../models/Images')(locale))

  getImageById: (req, res) => {
    const id = req.swagger.params.id.value
    const locale = req.swagger.params.locale.value
    Images[locale].findOne({_id: id}).lean().exec( (err, image) => {
```

Comment: What is the question? If all you are asking is "is this okay", then you should be posting on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: added the two ways I'm thinking. Didn't know about codereview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this is how I resolved it. Where it says Pictograms, could be Images as in the question

```
const setPictogramModel = require('../models/Pictograms')
const languages = [
  'ar',
  'bg',
  'en',
  'es',
  'pl',
  'ro',
  'ru',
  'zh'
]
const Pictograms = languages.reduce((dict, language)=> {
  dict[language]= setPictogramModel(language)
  return dict
}, {})

module.exports = {
  getPictogramById: (req, res) => {
    const id = req.swagger.params.idPictogram.value
    const locale = req.swagger.params.locale.value
    // Use lean to get a plain JS object to modify it, instead of a full model instance
    Pictograms[locale].findOne({id_image: id}).exec( (err, pictogram) => {
      if(err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
          message: 'Error getting pictograms. See error field for detail',
          error: err
        })
      }
      if(!pictogram) {
        return res.status(404).json( {
          message: `Error getting pictogram with id ${id}`,
          err
        })
      }
      return res.json(pictogram)
    })
  },
```